# Where to find ObjectBox nonsql database file on Android Emulator(using Windows) and how to open it?

Tags: objectbox

Where can I find ObjectBox nonsql database file on an Android Emulator(using Windows) and what program to use to open the database file to look at the saved records?

Comment: https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser may be an alternative that directly works without pulling any file from the device.

Comment: The ObjectBox Admin Data Browser is for a Web app. I am looking at an Android App on Windows 11 using Android Studio Emulator. If I use a sql database, then I can find a database file under C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.1\device-explorer\Pixel_API_Tiramisu [emulator-5554]\data\data\myappname\databases, where myappname is the name of the app. This is not the case with NONSQL Database like ObjectBox. I want to see records saved in a database.

Comment: If you want to look at the data for Android App, the Admin UI is the simplest way to go.

Comment: Hello Markus! It looks like Admin IU is the way to go. Thank You